# How to use lambda and api getaway to trigger a custom event?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to understand how The AWS api gateway works with lambda. What i am wanting to do is quite simple :

When I submit a basic form in a localhosted web page, this simple action should invoke a lambda function.

I know i need to use  aws api gateway to complete this action and i read some tutorials online but i can't figure out how to start a lambda function after a custom event.

Thanks yor any help.

Answer (score 4):

It is easier to understand if you work backwards. First, make your custom event handler. Amazon provides a good overview of what you need to do here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html

If you need more of a kick in the right direction, LithosTech has a well-written guide to handling FORM POST events in Lambda here:
http://lithostech.com/2015/10/aws-lambda-example-contact-form-handler/

At its simplest level, you're going to have a function that takes an `event` parameter and does something with its values:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
    // TODO: Do something with event.name, event.email, event.*, ...
}
```

After you make this function in a .JS file, upload it using the Lambda Web console - you can do it entirely from the command line, but it's easier to use the Web interface when you're first starting out. The biggest benefit to doing it this way is that during the creation process, you'll be asked if you want to make an API gateway endpoint for the function - say yes! This will automatically create a suitable entry for you and give you the details. Drop those in your form and you're off to the races!

Comment: Thanks for you reply. However my problem is not solved. How can i programmatically run the Api geteway to trigger a lambda function that i previously created. For example, in a form, each time i click on submit, the api gateway should automatically trigger my lambda function. How to do so ?